# ¿Por qué un vector creado dentro de un bucle for termina almacenando datos que no fueron asignados al mismo?

Tags: array, r, bucle-for, timezone

Buenas noches querida comunidad, me encuentro en la siguiente situación:

Tengo al vector llamado **file.names**, el cual es de tipo character y de longitud 60:

```
> head(files.names)
[1] "3B-HHR-E.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20140401-S140000-E142959.0840.V06B.HDF5"
[2] "3B-HHR-E.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20140401-S143000-E145959.0870.V06B.HDF5"
[3] "3B-HHR-E.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20140401-S150000-E152959.0900.V06B.HDF5"
[4] "3B-HHR-E.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20140401-S153000-E155959.0930.V06B.HDF5"
[5] "3B-HHR-E.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20140401-S160000-E162959.0960.V06B.HDF5"
[6] "3B-HHR-E.MS.MRG.3IMERG.20140401-S163000-E165959.0990.V06B.HDF5"
```

Todos los elementos del vector tienen la misma longitud y solamente cambian las fechas y horas. Mi propósito es crear un nuevo vector que contenga solamente las fechas y horas en formato POSIXct.

Sin embargo, las fechas y horas del vector **files.names** están en UTC y yo las necesito en la zona horaria **"America/Asuncion"**; para lo cual utilizo la función **lubridate::with_tz( )**.
El script utilizado es el siguiente:

```
files.names = list.files('C:/Users/Diego/Downloads/datosprueba')
new_vector = POSIXct(0)

for(k in 1:length(files.names)) {
  cadena = files.names [k]
  fecha = substr(cadena, start = 24, stop = 31)
  hora  = substr(cadena, start = 34, stop = 39)
  fh = paste(fecha,hora,sep = ' ')

  fechahora_UTC = ymd_hms(fh)

  fechahora_asuncion = with_tz(fechahora_UTC, tzone = "America/Asuncion")
  cat ("Iteracion: ", k)
  print (fechahora_asuncion)
  new_vector[k] = fechahora_asuncion
}
```

El código cumple la función de crear el nuevo vector, sin embargo, los valores cargados en **new_vector** son los de **fechahora_UTC**, cuando en el script se puede ver claramente que los valores que se están asignando a **new_vector** son los de **fechahora_asuncion**.

Es decir, **new_vector** almacena a los valores **fechahora_UTC** cuando debería estar almacenando a los valores **fechahora_asuncion**.

Al ejecutar el script, el comando **print(fechahora_asuncion)** confirma, que de hecho la conversión de UTC a "America/Asuncion" se realiza de la forma deseada.

```
Iteracion:  1[1] "2014-04-01 10:00:00 -04"
Iteracion:  2[1] "2014-04-01 10:30:00 -04"
Iteracion:  3[1] "2014-04-01 11:00:00 -04"
Iteracion:  4[1] "2014-04-01 11:30:00 -04"
Iteracion:  5[1] "2014-04-01 12:00:00 -04"
Iteracion:  6[1] "2014-04-01 12:30:00 -04"
```

Esos valores que devuelve print( ) son los que deberían ser almacenados en new_vector, sin embargo:

```
> new_vector [1:6]
[1] "2014-04-01 14:00:00 UTC" 
[2] "2014-04-01 14:30:00 UTC"
[3] "2014-04-01 15:00:00 UTC" 
[4] "2014-04-01 15:30:00 UTC"
[5] "2014-04-01 16:00:00 UTC"
[6] "2014-04-01 16:30:00 UTC"
```

new_vector almacena los datos UTC que corresponden a **fechahora_UTC** y no a **fechahora_asucion** que son los que realmente se están asignando a **new_vector** dentro del ciclo for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que defines un vector `new_vector` tipo `POSIXct`, para ir asignándole luego el valor con `tz`, pero no especificas la zona horaria, por lo que se usará el default de la función. Si revisamos el código de `POSIXct`, vemos que el default es `UTC`

```
function (length = 0L, tz = "UTC") 
{
    t0 <- if (is_utc(tz)) 
        origin
    else force_tz(origin, tz)
    .POSIXct(rep.int(t0, length), tz = tz)
}
<bytecode: 0x564e15d42db0>
<environment: namespace:lubridate>
```

Por lo que te sugiero, modificar por esto:

```
new_vector = POSIXct(0)
```

por:

```
new_vector = POSIXct(0, tz="America/Asuncion")
```

O bien crear el vector a partir del tipo de dato que retorna `with_tz()`

```
new_vector <- with_tz(fechahora_UTC, tzone = "America/Asuncion")
```

Esto último funciona, por que el vector se crea a partir del dato que entrega `with_tz()` y no asignado el valor a uno ya existente